# Spring injection bind toInstance

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, guice

Is there a way to bind an injected object to a specific instance using Spring DI similar to Google Guice's

```
bind(MyClass.class).toInstance(myclassobject);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the constructor or member variable is annotated with `@Autowired`, Spring will try to find a bean that matches the type of the Object. You can get similar functionality to the annotation using `@Qualifier`, for example:

```
bind(MyClass.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("main")).toInstance(myclassobject);
```

would become in Spring:

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("main") private MyClass myClassObject;

<bean name="myClassObject" class="example.MyClassImpl">
    <qualifier value="main"/>
</bean>
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation for more.