# Guice bind toInstance equality in Spring Dependency Injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, guice

i will explain the situation with an example. For instance i have a Settings class and i'm configuring some hostname,port information there. Like:

```
public class Settings {

@Inject
private User user;
```

In guice i can handle this with:

```
 private Injector injector;

 public void setInjector(){
 injector=Guice.createInjector( new AbstractModule(){
 @Override
        protected void configure(){
               bind( User.class ).toInstance(user);
        }
 }
}
```

When someone use `@Inject User user` then my code give him only my instance, **i mean there's only one user instance whereever developer create a user instance with Inject.**

How can i achieve this in spring can someone explain me ?

Note that: I just know there's an @Autowired annotation but how to achive this, is confusing :S

Thanks in advance

BTW: I couldn't get the point that mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970920/spring-injection-bind-toinstance)

Comment: Do you want Spring to create multiple instances of your user object?  Try "@Inject" and "@Dependent" if so.  I don't think that's what you're looking for though. If you want the same user everywhere you need to define the bean somewhere, in a java config class or through the xml http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype  The java config requires @Configuration and some setup for scanning in the xml.  Clarify what you're looking for and I might be able to help.

Comment: I always want same configured User object everywhere, can you please explain more about @Configuration and how can i use. I just tried it but couldnt make it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web app, you want to use something like Spring security and use a session-scoped object to control the user provided to the form.

Otherwise, you could do, something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class XYZConfig {

    @Bean(name="User")
    public User getUser() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

In your spring application context, you'd need to do:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz" />
```

Spring boot has a lot of basic samples of things you might need to do:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: i will test it tomorrow, but i will change the code new User to my configured User instance. But after that how can i retrive this user instance ? with @Autowired annotation ?

Comment: It should work with "@Inject, which Spring treats as the same as "@Autowired"  You really don't want the user to be the same for everyone logging in, but this should get you started. At a minimum, you're going to want to annotate the getUser method with "@Scope(value = "session")", but you're going to need to set up a user service and everything, but I'm probably assigning my constraints to your problem. And realistically, if a spring web app, use spring security.

Comment: It's not a WEB APP!! and should i add something special to my User class ? like @Service or something else ?

Comment: and when i use @Autowired User user class somewhere else it's NULL!